# How I save data on database table from django?

Tags: html, django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I made a django website where doctor and patient both can signup. Patient mark their problem and it will send to those doctor whom he/she want, like question asking on Quora. And I also want to save data in db

But my webpage when patient insert data it does not save in database.

**Models.py**

```
class patients(models.Model):
    fever=models.BooleanField()
    others=models.TextField()
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import patients
def patient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fever=request.POST['fever']
        others=request.POST['others']

        patient_details=patients(fever= fever,others = others)

        patient_details.save()

        return render(request, "patient")
    else:
        return render(request, "patient.html")
```

**Patient.html**

```
<form action="patient">
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><u>Mark Your Problems</u></label><br>
<!-- FEVER -->
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" name="fever" for="inlineCheckbox1">Fever     </label>
</div>

<!--Others-->
<h6 style="text-align:left;"><u>Others</u></h5>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="others" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"> SUBMIT </button>
</h6>



</form>
```

How I store these data on database ?

Answer (score 0):

try this line

```
patient_details=patients.objects.create(Fever= fever, others = others)
```

instead of :

```
patient_details=patients(Fever= fever, others = others)
```

Comment: same thing coming

Comment: are you getting any error or any message in console. try printing the value of fever and others in your view. Print(fever),print(others) and see if you are actually getting the values in your view.

Comment: also include the name attribute in html input field

  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1" name="fever">

Comment: I think i should not use BooleanField in models for cheakbox. What should I use can You Tell